# Using sapply (or apply) inside objective function for optim ; object in list element no longer recognized

Tags: r, apply, mathematical-optimization, sapply

I would like to use an objective function based on a list of elements, each of which is the result of applying a function over a dataframe (df) ((function is, say, variance of df's observations' "measure")). That is, I have a list of dfs. I naturally want to `sapply` my function over the list of dfs.

Without `sapply`, **this first block works.** It is for a single df, and so without the sapply command, where the function is min.RSS (calculation of standard errors, which we will like `optim` to minimize)

```
#setup dfs
list_dat <- array(list(), dim=c(2,1))
list_dat[[1]] =data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
               y=c(1,3,5,6,8,12,15,19))
list_dat[[2]] =data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                          y=c(1,3,5,6,8,12))
#define objective fn
min.RSS <- function(data, par) {
  with(data, sum((par[1] + par[2] * x - y)^2))
  }

#optimize : find minimum given starting values, feeding in the first element, namely the df 
result <- optim(c(0.5,0.5), min.RSS,   data = list_dat[[1]])
```

**The following does not work**, a block that includes `sapply`, coming back with an error

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found

**Can anyone please see why?**

```
#define new objective function based only on the first element, and optimize
min.RSS <- function(data, par) {
  sapply(list, function(data) with(data, sum((par[1] + par[2]* x - y)^2)))[[1]]
  }
result <- optim(c(0.5,0.5), min.RSS,   data = list_dat) # optimize, feeding in the list of (2) dfs
```

To explain what I don't understand, just using sapply without `optim` works as expected. I change the arguments `par[1]` `par[2]` being optimized over, into scalar(s). That is, the following also *works*

```
list2 <- sapply(list_dat, function(data) with(data, sum((1 + 2 * x - y)^2)))
```

Comment: The `list` inside your `sapply` should be `list_dat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `list_dat` is not a list, it is an array of lists.
2. Your definition of `min.RSS` defines `data` as it's argument, but then refers to `list`

```
#  You don't really need to preallocate the list, but if you insist
list_dat <- vector(length=2, mode='list')
list_dat[[1]] =data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
                          y=c(1,3,5,6,8,12,15,19))
list_dat[[2]] =data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                          y=c(1,3,5,6,8,12))


min.RSS <- function(list, par) {
    sapply(list, function(data) with(data, sum((par[1] + par[2]* x - y)^2)))[[1]]
}

 result <- optim(c(0.5,0.5), min.RSS,   list = list_dat)
```